# Remove duplicates where values are swapped across 2 columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a simple dataframe like this:

```
| id1 | id2 | location   | comment   |
|-----|-----|------------|-----------|
| 1   | 2   | Alaska     | cold      |
| 2   | 1   | Alaska     | freezing! |
| 3   | 4   | California | nice      |
| 4   | 5   | Kansas     | boring    |
| 9   | 10  | Alaska     | cold      |
```

The first two rows are duplicates because `id1` and `id2` both went to Alaska. It doesn't matter that their comment are different.

How can I remove one of these duplicates -- either one would be fine to remove.

I was first trying to sort `id1` and `id2`, then get the index where they are duplicated, then go back and use the index to subset the original df. But I can't seem to pull this off.

```
df <- data.frame(id1 = c(1,2,3,4,9), id2 = c(2,1,4,5,10), location=c('Alaska', 'Alaska', 'California', 'Kansas', 'Alaska'), comment=c('cold', 'freezing!', 'nice', 'boring', 'cold'))
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1` to `sort` by row for the 'id' columns, cbind with 'location' and then use `duplicated` to get a logical index that can be used for removing/keeping the rows.

```
df[!duplicated(data.frame(t(apply(df[1:2], 1, sort)), df$location)),]
#   id1 id2   location comment
#1   1   2     Alaska    cold
#3   3   4 California    nice
#4   4   5     Kansas  boring
#5   9  10     Alaska    cold
```

Comment: what do I do if my 'real' dataframe has 6 other columns that are similar to `location`: where it doesn't matter what the values are (but I'd like to keep them). Can I just pass them in like `c(df$location, df$col6, df$col7, df$col8)`?

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck  You can subset the dataset like `df[c("location", "col6", "col7", "col8")]`  If you are using that also in the duplicated, `duplicated(cbind(t(apply(....), df[c("location",...)]))`

Comment: I'm confused...sorry! You solution didn't have `cbind`. And I'm not sure I get what you mean. I just would like to carry all the rest of the columns along with me.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck  Instead of `cbind` i used `data.frame`

Comment: so do you think this will work? `df[!duplicated(data.frame(t(apply(df[1:2], 1, sort)), c(df$location, df$othercol1, df$othercol2))),]`?

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck  I would do `df[!duplicated(data.frame(t(apply(df[1:2], 1, sort)), df[c("location", "othercol1", "othercol2")])),]`   I think `c` wouldn't work because you are concatenating `vector`s.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118595/discussion-between-monica-heddneck-and-akrun).

Comment: For me, this worked fine in preserving all columns in my df: `df[!duplicated(data.frame(t(apply(df[1:2], 1, sort)))),]`