# Removing duplicates requires a transpose, but my dataframe is too large

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, transpose

I had asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649268/remove-duplicates-where-values-are-swapped-across-2-columns-in-r/38649301#38649301).  I had a simple dataframe, for which I was attempting to remove duplicates. Very basic question.

Akrun gave a great answer, which was to use this line:

```
df[!duplicated(data.frame(t(apply(df[1:2], 1, sort)), df$location)),]
```

I went ahead and did this, which worked great on the dummy problem.  But I have 3.5 million records that I'm trying to filter.

In an attempt to see where the bottleneck is, I broke the code into steps.

```
step1 <- apply(df1[1:2], 1, sort)
step2 <- t(step1)
step3 <- data.frame(step2, df1$location)
step4 <- !duplicated(step3)
final <- df1[step4, ,]
```

step 1 look quite a long time, but it wasn't the worst offender.
step 2, however, is clearly the culprit.

So I'm in the unfortunate situation where I'm looking for a way to transpose 3.5 million rows in R.  (Or maybe not in R. Hopefully there is some way to do it somewhere).

Looking around, I saw a few ideas

- install the WGCNA library, which has a `transposeBigData` function. Unfortunately this package is not longer being maintained, and I can't install all the dependencies.
- write the data to a csv, then read it in line by line, and transpose each line one at a time. For me, even writing the file run overnight with no completion.

This is really strange. I just want to remove duplicates. For some reason, I have to transpose a dataframe in this process. But I can't transpose a dataframe this large.

So I need a better strategy for either removing duplicates, or for transposing.  Does anyone have any ideas on this?

By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, with 15.6 GiB RAM, for which `cat /proc/cpuinfo` returns

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3630QM CPU @ 2.40GHz
cpu MHz     : 1200.000
cache size  : 6144 KB

Thanks.

```
df <- data.frame(id1 = c(1,2,3,4,9), id2 = c(2,1,4,5,10), location=c('Alaska', 'Alaska', 'California', 'Kansas', 'Alaska'), comment=c('cold', 'freezing!', 'nice', 'boring', 'cold'))
```

Comment: Are there only 2 `id_` columns to sort and search for duplicates? Which of the four columns you need to account for when searching for duplicates? Only `id1` and `id2`, or `location` too?

Comment: `id1`, `id2`, and `location` too!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A faster option would be using `pmin/pmax` with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!duplicated(data.table(pmin(id1, id2), pmax(id1, id2)))]
#     id1 id2   location comment
#1:   1   2     Alaska    cold
#2:   3   4 California    nice
#3:   4   5     Kansas  boring
#4:   9  10     Alaska    cold
```

If 'location' also needs to be included to find the `unique`

```
setDT(df)[!duplicated(data.table(pmin(id1, id2), pmax(id1, id2), location))]
```

Comment: Got this error -- have you seen it before? I'm it googling now. `Error in duplicated.default(pmin(id1, id2), pmax(id1, id2),  : 
  'fromLast' must be TRUE or FALSE`

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck  I am using your example and there is no error for me.  I am using R 3.3.0 and data.table_1.9.7, but 1.9.6 shoudl also work

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck  Please check on a random subset of rows in your dataset to see where exactly you get the error and then use `dput` to show that small dataset

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck  Do you have NA elements in 'id1', 'id2'?

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck  Can you try with `setDT(df)[!duplicated(pmin(id1, id2), pmax(id1, id2), location, fromLast = FALSE)]` (though we don't have to specify for default cases, but based on your error)

Comment: I guess the `duplicated` call does not seem valid -- `pmax(id1, id2)` is passed as "incomparables" and `location` is passed as "nmax" in the current case. I think it should be a separate `duplicated` for each component and, then `"&"` the results.

Comment: @alexis_laz I think you are right.  I need to construct a data.table or `cbind` .

Comment: I don't know exactly what you did, I'll have to look at the change you made. But it worked. Amazingly fast. This is pretty shocking. Thank you for putting in so much effort.

Answer (score 1):

So after struggling with this for most of the weekend (grateful for plenty of selfless help from the illustrious @akrun), I realized that I would need to go about this in a completely different manner.

Since the dataframe was simply too large to process in memory, I ended up using a strategy where I pasted together a (string) key and column-bound it onto the dataframe. Next, I collapsed the key and sorted the characters. Here I could use `which` to get the index of the rows that contained non-duplicate keys. With that I could filter the my dataframe.

```
df_with_key <- within(df,  key <- paste(boxer1, boxer2, date, location, sep=""))

strSort <- function(x)
  sapply(lapply(strsplit(x, NULL), sort), paste, collapse="")

df_with_key$key <- strSort(df_with_key$key)

idx <- which(!duplicated(df_with_key$key))

final_df <- df[idx,]
```

Comment: Can you check if the comment posted by alexis_laz is the root of the problem.  I updated the post.